# Make an automated function for the date

Tags: mongodb, metabase

My company is using metabase for queries
I have the data made for a custom date for the query
But we want to put this query in the "pulse" to get mails everyday regarding this query.
Is there any way the date in this query can change everyday.to get results of last "30 days","7 days" and last day data.

In short I am looking for a function so that it can track "my current date" so that I could do "my current date"-30 to get data to last 30days

```
[{"$lookup":{
    "from":"institutions",

    "localField":"institute_id",

    "foreignField":"_id",

    "as":"insti"
}},

{"$group":{
    "_id":"$institute_id",

    "name":{"$first":"$insti.name"},

    "applicants1":{"$addToSet":{"$cond":[{"$gte":["$created_at",ISODate("2019-06-30T00:00:00.000Z")]},"$candidate_id",null]}},

    "applicants2":{"$addToSet":{"$cond":[{"$gte":["$created_at",ISODate("2019-07-23T00:00:00.000Z")]},"$candidate_id",null]}},

    "applicants3":{"$addToSet":{"$cond":[{"$gte":["$created_at",ISODate("2019-07-29T00:00:00.000Z")]},"$candidate_id",null]}}
}},
{"$project":{
    "_id":0,

    "name":"$name",

    "last_30_days":{"$subtract":[{"$size":"$applicants1"},1]},

    "last_7_days":{"$subtract":[{"$size":"$applicants2"},1]},

    "last_1_day":{"$subtract":[{"$size":"$applicants3"},1]}

}},{"$sort":{"last_30_days":-1}}
]
```

I tried used `"$currentDate()-30"` for last 30days query but it doesn't work

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to try a simpler query, which filters data for the last 30 days, using the query builder, and, then, show the generated SQL? That way, you could figure it out how to perform that kind of filter. I don't know MongoDB, but if feels to me that is rather related to it than to Metabase itself.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using this in my Mysql queries

**For last 30 Days**

```
where date(created_at) >=  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

**For Last 7 Days**

```
where date(created_at) >=  DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

**For Current Date**

```
where date(created_at) >= CURDATE()
```

Comment: INTERVAL needs to be 7 for last 7 days

Comment: classic lazy mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "$currentDate()-30" you can use {$add:['$applicants1','3000']}
here 3000 is in milliseconds. you can also use multiply operator instead of passing the value in milliseconds. as $multiply:['desireddays','216000']
the whole query will become {$add:['$applicants1',{$multiply:['-desireddays','216000']}]}

for past days pass the value in negative ex: -30 in your case

reference https://www.hypertrends.com/2017/03/dateadd-functionality-mongodb/